# MYSQL: best utf setting for ACCENT sensitive but CASE insensitive

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive, diacritics, utf, accent-sensitive

For example, ἐν or Ἐν are the same, but should be distinguished from ἕν/Ἓν. I've tried utf8_bin which seems to be the closest, but is also case sensitive.

Comment: `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` seems to be the only collation with needed properties combination. See `SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%_as_ci'`.

Comment: there a lots of them see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html everything that ios as and ci should do it

Comment: @nbk *there a lots of them see ..* A lot? I have provided one collation in the comment above, what is the second one?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select 'ἐν' = 'Ἐν' collate utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;
+----------------------------------------------+
| 'ἐν' = 'Ἐν' collate utf8mb4_0900_as_ci       |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                            1 |
+----------------------------------------------+

mysql> select 'ἐν' = 'ἕν' collate utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;
+----------------------------------------------+
| 'ἐν' = 'ἕν' collate utf8mb4_0900_as_ci       |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                            0 |
+----------------------------------------------+
```